# Incorporate this appropriate XKCD comic in our doc?

Tags: discussion

Is there an appropriate place in our documentation to integrate today's quite-relevant XKCD comic?

[image: XKCD comic 2024]

[Direct link to comic](https://www.xkcd.com/2024/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally really like this comic, as most xkcd strips in general.

Unfortunately, it doesn't really fit on the tour page or any other page that moderators are able to edit on a per-site basis.